# Reflection in water

Tags: reflection

Suppose there is lake. And a cloud is at a height h above it. The reflection of the cloud will be at the same depth in the lake as the height of the cloud or at the surface of the lake or at the base of the lake or somewhere else?

Comment: Where is your attempt at solving the problem? Please read [How to ask homework questions?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange).

Comment: What do you think is the answer and why?

Answer (score 1):

it should be at the same  depth  as height

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/163106)

Comment: This seems ok as an answer to me, even though it is very short. @KyleOman : This is not a comment. It is clearly an attempt to answer.